# Differential equation with homogeneous Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The general solution of the heat equation by separation of the variables is
$$X(x)=a \cos\omega x + b \sin \omega x$$
**Dirichlet**

with the Dirichlet boundary conditions
$$u_t = \kappa u_{xx}(x,t)\\
u(0,t)=T_0, u(L,t)=T_L\\
u(x,0)=f(x)$$
Since the steady state codition is linear between two Dirichlet boundary conditions, we have
$$u(x,t)=u_s(x)+\nu(x,t)$$
and then we can apply new boundary conditions in the general solution
$$\nu(0,t)=\nu(L,t)=0$$

---

**Neumann**

with Nwumann homogenous boundary conditions, we already have
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0$$
and then the steady state condition is not required, we can apply the boundary conditions to the general solution.

---

**Dirichlet-Neumann**

Consider the boundary conditions for a metal bar with an end at a fixed temperature and the end is insulated:
$$u(0,t)=T_1\\
u_x(L,t)=0$$

How can we apply these boundary conditions to the general solution to eliminate one term and obtain the coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining $u = T_1 + v$ and demanding $v(0,t) = v_x(L,t) = 0$?
Notice that the problem for $v$ becomes homogenous (PDE and BCs) with initial condition $v(x,0) = f(x) - T_1$.